# Using Single date filter for date range in superset custom filter

Tags: filter, apache-superset

In Superset, I would like to use only single date selection but use that for range of date e.g. 7 days back.
for example:
Date selection : 2020-04-18  to 2020-04-18

Expected date: 2020-04-11 to 2020-04-18
Reason is that most dashboard required single date but some required time series which shows last 7 days result.

Here is the code I prepare in custom query.

```
    SELECT  distinct(dt) FROM mytable
WHERE 
    dt >= date_add('day', -7, from_iso8601_timestamp('{{ to_dttm.isoformat() }}'))
    AND
    dt <= date_add('day', 0, from_iso8601_timestamp('{{ to_dttm.isoformat() }}'))
```

this is result from json. It did put extra query WHERE, it runs pass but only 1 date shown.

```
SELECT distinct(dt)  FROM mytable\n
WHERE dt >= date_add('day', -7, from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-04-18T00:00:00'))\n     
AND dt <= date_add('day', 0, from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-04-18T00:00:00'))) AS \"expr_qry\"\n
WHERE \"dt\" >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-04-18T00:00:00')\n  
AND \"dt\" <= from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-04-18T00:00:00')\nLIMIT 1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom query using Jinja filters.
You can get the value selected in your filter box using the `filter_values()`
function.

`{% set date_ref =   filter_values('my_date')[0] %}`

Then you can write your custom query using classic MySQL functions. In your query, recall the Jinja variable using {{ }}. For instance,

`AND date >= DATE_ADD({{date_ref}}, INTERVAL -7 DAYS)`